# How to get variables from the command line in Java?

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I've finished writing a java program about a drinksBot. I just have one issue; I need two variables from the command line to be saved as int variables eg.

The user types in:

java DrinksBot 30 40

and the program begins to run, and saves

```
int cupStock=  30;

int shotStock = 40;  //or whatever the user typed into the command line.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I'm new to this!

My code begins like this:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class DrinksBot {

        static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

           public static void main(String[] args) {

              System.out.print("Hello, what's your name? I have"+cupStock+" cups left, and " + shotStock+" shots left.);
```

... continues to run rest of program etc.

Answer (score 3):

Read it from `args[]` array in main method. The variables passed in command line get assigned to String array defined in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String cupStock = args[0];
      String shotStock = args[1];
      System.out.print("Hello, what's your name? I have"+cupStock+" cups left, and " + shotStock+" shots left.);
}
```

run as `java DrinksBot 30 40` where the 30 is cupStock and the 40 is shotStock

**Update:**

to get the value as integer just convert the string to int

```
int cupStock = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int shotStock = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks- it must be a String? I need shotStock and cupStock to be ints so I can add/subtract them later in my program.... how would I do this? When i try to declare them as int it doesn't work

Comment: @Mik just conver them to int, I updated the answer. Its just a conversion. Handle exception `NumberFormatException` for better program.

Comment: Thanks- I'm doing that but it's still not working.

public static void main(String[] args) {

     String cupStock = args[0];
     String shotStock = args[1];

      Int cupStock = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      Int shotStock = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

Comment: @Mik instead of keeping `String shotStock`  just keep `int shotStock = Integer.parseInt(args[0])`. You can't keep two variables with same name. And don't forget to assign the 1st element of the array to shotStock. `int shotStock = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are stored in the `args` array passed to the `main` method. The first argument is the first element `args[0]`, the second is `args[1]` and so on. Since the elements are of type `String`, you can convert to `int` using `Integer.parseInt(String)`:

```
int cupStock = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

int shotStock = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

Of course you should validate the input before doing this by checking the length of the array, otherwise an exception would occur:

```
if(args.length < 2) {
   // print a message to the user and exit
}
```

Comment: @Mik The arguments are of type `String`. You need to convert to `int`. Fixed.